# Callback of a derived class from wxEvtHandler never get called

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a class which derives from wxEvtHandler. It creates a button and bind a "click" callback.This callback never get called. If I create same button in the wxFrame, everything works fine. Am I missing something ? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

const int ID1 = 1;
const int ID2 = 2;

struct Derived : public wxEvtHandler
{
    Derived(wxFrame* frame)
    {
        auto btn = new wxButton(frame, ID1, "A", wxPoint(10, 20));
        Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, &Derived::Click, this, ID1);
    }

    void Click(wxCommandEvent& ev)
    {
        auto dial = new wxMessageDialog(0, "Button B does not works fine!", "", wxOK);
        dial->ShowModal();
    }
};

struct MainFrame : public wxFrame
{
    MainFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "")
    {
        auto pane = new Derived(this);

        auto btn = new wxButton(this, ID2, "B", wxPoint(10, 50));
        Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, &MainFrame::Click, this, ID2);

    }

    void Click(wxCommandEvent& ev)
    {
        auto dial = new wxMessageDialog(0, "Button B works fine!", "", wxOK);
        dial->ShowModal();
    }
};

struct Application : public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit()
    {
        auto simple = new MainFrame();
        simple->Show(true);
        return true;
    }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(Application)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use
`btn->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, &Derived::Click, this, ID1);`

**The rationale goes like this**: When the button wants to process the click event it calls `GetEventHandler()` to find the bound handler (Click() in your code). But `GetEventHandler()` returns its parent (a wxFrame) event handler, which has **not** bound "Click". So does nothing.

Setting Derived as the handler by using `btn->SetEventHandler(this);` or `btn->PushEventHandler(this);` before calling `Bind()` makes `GetEventHandler()` to return Derived which does have Click handler, and then the event is processed.

But then another issue appears: when the button is deleted all its eventhandlers must be popped before (otherwise some pending event may keep a dangling deleted pointer). This issue forces you to call `PopEventHandler()` at the button deletion... Forget all of this and use `btn->Bind(...)`

Comment: Your solution is correct, but not the rationale. `GetEventHandler()` returns the object itself, i.e. the button, by default. The problem is that `this->Bind()` called in the example binds to `Derived` object itself which never gets the event -- because why/how should it? -- while the frame is the parent of the button and so does get the event as it bubbles up.